# Un-standardising data with known minimum value

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, standardization

If you have a vector of standardised data and don't have access to the original vector. I know that generally if you don't have any information on the original data (mean and sd) you can't reverse the process. But, is it possible if you know the actual **minimum** value and use an arbitrary **maximum** value?

Comment: Would un-standardising data be a better title for your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the actual maximum, you could find $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and reverse transform your data. That's because you'll also have access to the minimum and maximum values in the standardised data and can solve the following equations:
$$z_{min}=\frac{x_{min}-\mu}{\sigma}, \ \ z_{max}=\frac{x_{max}-\mu}{\sigma}$$

But, if you use an arbitrary maximum, there is no guarantee that you'll find the correct $\mu,\sigma$ for your data. However, as your maximum estimate gets better, your reverse transform gets better as well.